# ReLU vs sigmoid in mnist example

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, image-classification

PLEASE NOTE: I am not trying to improve on the following example. I know you can get over 99% accuracy. The whole code is in the question. When I tried this simple code I get around 95% accuracy, if I simply change the activation function from sigmoid to relu, it drops to less than 50%. Is there a theoretical reason why this happens?

I have found the following example online:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.utils import np_utils

(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X_train = X_train.reshape(60000, 784)     
X_test = X_test.reshape(10000, 784)

Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train, classes)     
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_test, classes)

batch_size = 100      
epochs = 15

model = Sequential()     
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=784)) 
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))     
model.add(Dense(10)) 
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='sgd')

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1)

score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=1)
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

This gives about 95% accuracy, but if I change the sigmoid with the ReLU, I get less than 50% accuracy. Why is that?

Comment: Compare with [keras'](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py) own relu example.

Comment: I want to understand why, in this example, the relu would do so much worse than the sigmoid. They use a different optimizer. Doesn't sgd work well with relu?

Comment: Either your model did not converge and/or it overfit. I'm going to lean more towards the second option since the documentation used dropout (regularization) and you did not. You can debug this problem by drawing the learning curve for the test and training sets.

Comment: The question is simple: why it works fine with sigmoid and not relu? None of the comments are even addressing the question.

Comment: What is your training accuracy with RELU?

Comment: What are the Hyper Parameters for the Optimizer (Step Size for instance)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took your exact code, replaced

```
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

by

```
model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

and indeed I experienced the same problem than you: only 55% accuracy, which is bad...

**Solution**: I rescaled the input image values from [0, 255] to [0,1] and it worked: **93% accuracy** with ReLU! (inspired from [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py)):

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.utils import np_utils

(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X_train = X_train.reshape(60000, 784)     
X_test = X_test.reshape(10000, 784)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32') / 255
X_test = X_test.astype('float32') / 255

Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train, 10)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_test, 10)

batch_size = 100
epochs = 15

model = Sequential()     
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=784)) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(10)) 
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='sgd')

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1)

score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=1)
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Output:

> Test accuracy: 0.934

---

Potential explanation: when using an input in [0, 255], then when doing the weighted sum for the layer $L$: $z = a^{(L-1)} w^{(L)} + b^{(L)}$, the value $z$ will often be big too. If $z$ is often big (or even if it's often > 0), let's say around 100, than $ReLU(z) = z$, and we totally lose the "non-linear" aspect of this activation function! Said in another way: if the input is in [0, 255], then $z$ is often far from 0, and we totally avoid the place where *"interesting non-linear things" are going on* (around 0 the ReLU function is non linear and looks like `__/`)... Now when the input is in [0,1], then the weighted sum $z$ can often be close to 0: maybe it sometimes goes below 0 (since the weights are randomly-initialized on [-1, 1], it's possible!), sometimes higher than 0, etc. Then more neuron activation/deactivation is happening... This could be a potential explanation of why it works better with input in [0, 1].

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort (+1). My question though, is why is that? What is the theoretical interpretation?

Comment: Your argument seems reasonable. If you would like to add a short comment in the text of your answer (so, no need to read the comments) I will accept your answer.

Comment: @user It's done!

Answer (score 2):

I got around 98% accuracy using ReLu activation function. I have used the following architecture :

1. fully connected layer with 300 hidden units
2. ReLu activation
3. fully connected layer with 10 hidden units
4. Softmax layer
5. Output Clipping 1e-10 to 0.999999 to avoid log(0) and value greater than 1
6. Cross entropy loss

I think you should add output clipping and then train it, hope that will work fine.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer seems to be confirming what @Basj says in his comments on why relu is not converging while sigmoid is. +1 but still does not answer my question on why. I think the comments in the other answer explain that.

Answer (score -1):

Because with MNIST, you are trying to predict based on probabilities.

The sigmoid function squishes the $x$ value between $0$ and $1$. This helps to pick the most probable digit that matches the label.

The ReLU function doesn't squish anything. If the $x$ value is less than $0$, the the output is $0$. If its more than $0$, the answer is the $x$ value itself. No probabilities are being created.

Honestly, I'm suprised you got anything more than 10% when you plug it in.

Comment: I think he means he changed the hidden layer activation from sigmoid to RELU, which should not be a problem as long as the output layer still has softmax.

Comment: @daleadil as Imran said, the hidden layer can have relu as the activation function, this has nothing to do with probability